# How to run Steam from the Xfce desktop?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, xfce, steam

I've installed Steam on Debian 7.0 without any hassle, and I can run it by typing `steam &`.

I've set it as a desktop launcher in Xfce, but when I ran it, nothing happened.

Then I've check the "Run in terminal" option, and saw that it printed error messages about `GLIBC_2.5` missing, which I had previously installed in order to get Steam to work.

I suspected that it probably needs my environment variables, and that Xfce isn't running it as "me" (why?).

After that, I've created a `runsteam` script and linked the desktop launcher to it. The script tried to execute my `.bashrc` to get the environment variables, but it had its permission denied.

I've set the variables in `runsteam` myself (copied from `.bashrc`), but the terminal window simply flashes and exits before I can see anything.

These are the relevant contents of my `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/name/bin/
STEAMLIBS=${HOME}/steamlib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${STEAMLIBS}

export STEAMLIBS
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

How can I run Steam from my Xfce desktop?

Comment: So what is your actual problem, I mean, what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy to fix bug, please see the 7th entry on my blog post about fixing common Steam on Debian Linux problems: http://www.yannbane.com/2013/02/how-to-steam-on-linux-debian-70.html.

Solution:

1. Right click on desktop
2. Create launcher...
3. Start writing "Steam" into the name box, and then select it from the suggestion.
4. Create

Try to run it! I doesn't work, does it? Well, neither did mine, but I've figured out how to fix it:

`sudo mousepad /usr/bin/steam`, after the line that begins with a '#!' (shebang) add:

```
STEAMLIBS=${HOME}/steamlib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${STEAMLIBS}

export STEAMLIBS
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

1. Completely quit Steam.
2. Try your new launcher.

Comment: Please include the important points of your solution in this post or you risk it being deleted as "not an answer."